# I want my Android Fragment to cover the MainActivity screen (I don't want to see any MainActivity text, buttons, etc.)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This seems to be such a fundamental question that I'm embarrassed to ask it, but I'm so frustrated by my `Fragment` learning curve that I'll expose my ignorance.

An example in a textbook that cuts a lot of corners that make expanding them difficult, if they even work, had no button to click; `MainActivity` simply loaded `FragmentA`. OK, keep it basic. I get that.

So I added a button to `MainActivity` to click to load `FragmentA`, but the button shows on the `FragmentA` screen, sort of like this (not an actual screen shot, but close):

[image]

**How do I prevent that?** Should I use a second `Activity` instead of a `Fragment`? Since this endeavor is to be utilized in a much larger project, I don't want to do anything considered not best practice. I realize that the main use of `Fragment` is to enable side-by-side "screens" on devices that are large enough. That's not what I want to do, but it IS possible to accomplish what I want with a `Fragment`, isn't it?

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
                          super.onCreate(       savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   }

  public void btnLoadFragmentAByClick(View view)
  {
    FragmentA fragmentA;
                                                          fragmentA = new FragmentA();

    FragmentTransaction ft ;
                        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.layout_container, fragmentA);
                        ft.addToBackStack("example");
                        ft.commit();
  }
}
```

`FragmentA.java`

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater _inflater,
                           ViewGroup                          _container,
                           Bundle         _savedInstanceState)
  {

        return _inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,
                                                              _container,
                             false);

    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android           ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools             ="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width    ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height   ="match_parent"
    tools:context           =".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:id           ="@+id/layout_container"
       android:orientation  ="vertical"
       android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
   </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id           ="@+id/btnLoadFragmentA"
        android:text         ="Load Fragment A"
        android:onClick="btnLoadFragmentAByClick"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`fragment_a.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android           ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width    ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height   ="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width    ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height   ="wrap_content"
        android:text            ="Layout for fragment A"
        android:textAppearance  ="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

I realize that I could hide the `MainActiviy` button (and any other objects) before loading `FragmentA` and show them after returning, but I was hoping for a one-or-two-line "fix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I prevent that?

Well, to some extent, you don't, insofar as this has nothing to do with fragments.

Your `activity_main.xml` has the `Button` floating over top of the `LinearLayout` (???) that you are using for your fragment container. If you do not want the `Button` floating over top of the fragment container, then fix the layout file to not have the `Button` floating over top of the fragment container.

> I realize that I could hide the MainActiviy button (and any other objects) before loading FragmentA and show them after returning, but I was hoping for a one-or-two-line "fix".

The typical solution for full-UI replacement using fragments is to have everything in fragments. Your `replace()` would replace your original fragment with a replacement. So, in this case, your `Button` would be managed by one fragment, and clicking the `Button` would `replace()` that fragment with another fragment. Given that your `FragmentTransaction` has `addToBackStack()`, pressing BACK would get rid of the replacement fragment and return you to your `Button` fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare--Thanks. I thought that my `Button` placement was weird before posting, but didn't know how to fix it. Now that I know that's part of the problem, I'll get on it. I just finished successfully changing this project to have no fragments but two activities. But I'll try placing the button more sanely. Like I'd said, it was an attempt to take a lame example and add something reasonable to it, but as I also said, I just can't get my head around fragments. I note from Googling that there are those who are against them, which made me switch to activity instead of fragment.